# How to retrieve data from Firebase, set it to a global variable, then pass it to the next view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, segue

First and for all, this question is regarding iOS, not android. Hopefully it won't get marked as duplicated to the android one again.

Secondly, to explain clearly, these are my intentions on how the app should run:

1. Perform checks inside of the "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier"
2. Check for empty username and password. If empty, return false and display alert

**NOTE**: I am able to do up till point 2. I know how to retrieve the data from firebase. The problem lies with point 3 onwards.

3. Else, proceed on and compare data in the firebase
4. If a match is found, get the documentID and set it to the global variable and return TRUE so that the prepareForSegue method is able to run.
5. Else, return FALSE and display alert that no matching credentials

**THE PROBLEM**

I did ALOT of research for solution on stack overflow, and I understand its something related to the async thingly where the code OUTSIDE would run first. However, I can't find a single solution related with shouldPerformSegue method.

I tried out the completionHandler method though. However, that piece of code cannot return true or false inside that method, in return, unable to determine if the segue should be performed or not. Also, data can only be retrieved within that method when I need that userID to be passed to other view controllers.

Here is the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier code (Pardon me if the formatting is off because I don't normally ask question in stack overflow, but I can't help it because this is irritating me as I can't find a solution to it after a full day combing stack overflow. Do not mind the "return true" though, cause I still need to access other view controllers in the mean time, hence, apart from the empty checks, I set it to return true for now.):

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        let username : String = outUsername.text!
        let password : String = outPassword.text!
        if username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Username and/or password cannot be empty", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        } else {
            db.collection("user").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if err != nil {
                    print("Error getting documents")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let username02 : String = (document["username"] as? String)!
                        let password02 : String = (document["password"] as? String)!
                        if username02 == username && password02 == password {
                            self.userID = document.documentID
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @unique27, if I understood your use case correctly, you are creating a Login Controller to authenticate a user and then fetch the data based on that user. I believe that you should apply the so-called "separation of concerns principle" here. I would create a Login Controller where you authenticate the user and perform the segue. Bear in mind that you can pass in variables to the next Controller. Then, from the next Home Controller, I would fetch the data based on the current user `let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/sllopis/TripXperience/blob/sergioUI/TripXperience/Controllers/LoginViewController.swift) a project of mine that can give you a brief idea of what I am describing above. While it might not give you a straight solution, this will clearly point you in the right direction. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do what you want in `shouldPerformSegue`; that function needs you to return true/false, but your Firebase query will return asynchronously, after you have already returned from the function. You could implement an action handler on your login button where you validate the username/password, perform the Firebase operations and then invoke the segue if all is ok from the Firebase completion handler. Don't forget to dispatch the segue on the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yep I did tried the IBAction method before posting for help. Didn't work because I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the info from Firebase and then pass it via the segue. Many suggested using prepareForSegue to pass information... As a result I don't know how to use shouldPerformSegue to pass the information. For your info, the userID to be retrieved is going to 4 different controllers via a tab bar controller...

Comment: You can’t do it in `shouldPerform`. Once you have the data you update your data model object and invoke the segue using `performSegueWithIdentifier`. In `prepareForSegue` you can pass your data model object to the destination.

Comment: @sllopis Thanks for the codes. However, I don't get the Auth() method. If I am not wrong, that's for the firebase authentication? For me this project is more like a sample proposal hence for now I am just trying to come up with just a simple login. Could had been easier with just using the link web services but unfortunately it was suggested to use firebase instead. Hence, I have been stuck here... Also the last module for completion and its frustrating right now.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there some sort of code for me to reference? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to set up a programmatic segue?  That is all that you need. Remove the segue from the button and create the segue from the view controller itself. Give it an identifier so that you can invoke it when you are ready.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just tried it out and I got confused... I do know how to set up a programmatic segue, its the passing I am getting confused at... I normally do Android hence iOS is a bit complicated for me to understand. I am quite new to ios

Comment: Store the values you need in properties of your current view controller (or better, store the values in a model object and hold a reference to that on a property of your current view controller). Then in prepare for segue you can assign the values to your destination view controller as shown in the answer below

Comment: @Paulw11 But I can't set the ID to a global variable because its getting retrieved from Firebase. In other words the code below runs first before the ID is even populated.

Comment: That's why you invoke the segue from the completion handler that runs after the Firebase data ha sheen retrieved.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi thanks for your help, I managed to get it working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying for numerous days, finally able to get it working right, although loading is a bit slow, but for now that will do since it's just a sample prototype application. If any of you encounter empty population after retrieval from Firebase and need to pass that data to another controller, here is how I did it:

IBAction from button code:

```
@IBAction func actLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let username : String = outUsername.text!
    let password : String = outPassword.text!
    if username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Username and/or password cannot be empty", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        var userID : String = ""
        var recordFound : Bool = false
        db.collection("user").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Error getting documents")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let username02 : String = (document["username"] as? String)!
                    let password02 : String = (document["password"] as? String)!
                    if username02 == username && password02 == password {
                        userID = document.documentID
                        recordFound = true
                    }
                }
                if recordFound == true {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextCtrl", sender: userID)
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter a valid account credential.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prepare for segue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let tabBarCtrller = segue.destination as? UITabBarController, let userID = sender as? String {
            // To retrieve from Firebase once user and password login is in place
            let userID : String = userID
            // To Book Now controller
            let navCtrl = tabBarCtrller.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
            let bknctrl = navCtrl.topViewController as! BookNowScreen01
            // To By Date controller
            let navCtrl02 = tabBarCtrller.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
            let bdctrl = navCtrl02.topViewController as! DateDurationScreen01
            // To By Room controller
            let navCtrl03 = tabBarCtrller.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController
            let brctrl = navCtrl03.topViewController as! RoomScreen01
            // To View Bookings controller
            let navCtrl04 = tabBarCtrller.viewControllers![3] as! UINavigationController
            let vbctrl = navCtrl04.topViewController as! ViewBookings

            bknctrl.userIDfromLogin = userID
            bdctrl.userIDfromLogin = userID
            brctrl.userIDfromLogin = userID
            vbctrl.userIDfromLogin = userID
        }

        outUsername.text = ""
        outPassword.text = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in **else** check is that :

You perform an async task, so what happens when you go through **else** check is that you return **true** before the data is retrieved from **firebase**.

So what you need to do is to use completionHandler or some notification and change the function return type to void like this :

---

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?, completionHandler:  @escaping ( _ shouldPerformSegue : Bool, _ userId : String) ->())  {
    let username : String = outUsername.text!
    let password : String = outPassword.text!
    if username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Username and/or password cannot be empty", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        completionHandler(false,"")
    } else {
        db.collection("user").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Error getting documents")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let username02 : String = (document["username"] as? String)!
                    let password02 : String = (document["password"] as? String)!
                    if username02 == username && password02 == password {
                        completionHandler(true,document.documentID)

                    }else{ 
                        completionHandler(false,"")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your solution today, unfortunately, the override method does not work... Just shows "Method does not override any method from its superclass" which meant the override has to be removed...

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that shouldPerformSegue is a wrong choice for async tasks you must separate this in a function like the answer  and call it by your self

Answer (score 0):

I assumed after successful login you have received your data (self.userID = document.documentID). then you can use that data in many way...

**Method 1: UserDefaults**
after successful login set your user id in to UserDefaults. like

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "userLoggedIn")
UserDefaults.standard.set(documentID, forKey: "userId")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and your next homeViewController you can get back, like

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userLoggedIn")  // true 
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")  //documentID
```

**Method 2: Segue**

set received value to global var of login ViewController and use it in performSegue.

call your Segue

```
self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
```

auto perform method, set your global value to homeViewController variable. i assume HomeViewController have var userID..

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

                if (segue.identifier == "loginToMain") {
                    if let target = segue.destination as? homeViewController
                    {
                        target.fromLogin = true
                        target.userId = self.userId
                    }
                }
    }
```

Hope, it helps..

*stackoverflow is always useful*

Comment: Hi, I tried out your method. Unfortunately, it does not work still. What I needed was to retrieve the info if there are matching records. If not, an alert to be displayed in shouldPerformSegue. As I am fetching from Firebase, due to the Async nature of Firebase, the global variable and the defaults are both going to be empty...